# PDFLib dll not working in .net4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was converted my .net2.0 project into .net4.0.

Now I could use pdflib.dll.
I recieved the below error.

> "Declaration referenced in a method implementation cannot be a final method.  Type: 'PDFLibNet.xPDFBinaryReader'.  Assembly: 'PDFLibNet, Version=1.0.6.6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=26d87f7d66fb2aee'."

In .net2.0 and net3.5 it hasworked for me but not in .net4.0.

How can I handle this?

I need any suggestions.

Comment: Is it [this one](http://www.pdflib.com/download/pdflib-family/pdflib-8/), and is it a .NET 1.1 assembly? I've had trouble with 1.1 assemblies in .NET 4 before. Can you recompile it at .NET 4, or ask your supplier too?

Comment: @101084_see got any soln.... same issue i'm facing now :(... help me

Answer (score 2):

You should use .NET framework 3.5 or lower! This dll does not work with .Net 4.0 or higher.